# Java and C# Binary Character format differences

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I'm trying to write a character through the network to be read by Java. In C# I'm using a `BinaryWriter` and in Java all of my data is being placed into a `ByteBuffer`.

I'm reading that in C# a `Character` is 2bytes, because of it's encoding, however I'm also aware that in Java a `Character` is two byts as-well.

Judging based on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putChar(char)

I'm assuming that a character in Java is actually only a single byte? How can I go about writing and exchanging characters over the network?

Comment: What channel are you using? sockets? REST? SOAP?

Comment: @matcheek -- Sockets. Didn't know this was relevant to the question, sorry.  TcpClient.

Comment: You need to make sure that you use the same encoding on both ends. Other than that I cannot see why this would not work

Answer (score 0):

Find out what specific encoding is being used on the Windows side when serializing the string onto the socket, then on the Java side construct the string from the bytes using the corresponding encoding.  For example, if Windows C# really serializes using the original two byte unicode encoding, now called "UCS-2", you would use:

```
String string = new String(bytes, "UCS-2");
```

However, I think it's likely that you can serialize on Windows using a more compact encoding, such as UTF-8 which encodes most characters in one byte.  In that case you would use

```
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Note that Java uses a two byte representation of characters for strings that are resident in memory, but when serializing and deserializing, usually a more compact encoding such as UTF-8 is used.  For more on Java Strings see the javadoc at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29